# Need help on proof

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

How to prove $p(a \cap \bar b)=p(a)+p(a\cup b)$?

I tried substitution for $\bar b$, but that did not work.

I know of the identity $p(a \cap \bar b)= p(a)+p(a \cup b)$.

I suspect deMorgans laws is in there but not sure how to apply it.

Comment: What  you want to prove  is palpably false: both terms on the right are individually larger than the term on the left and hence so is their sum.

Comment: What are you complaining about @Dilip Sarwate ? This gives a new way to break the unity barrier in probability. True, the unity barrier has been broken before, but it's always interesting to see new ways to do it https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/can-a-probability-distribution-value-exceeding-1-be-ok/160979#160979 .

Comment: I possibly wrote it wrong . It was probably p( a n b ‘)= p(a) - p(a n b)

Comment: @larry mintz  Use a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing that I can think of to fix your equality is

$$p(a \cap \bar{b})=p(a)-p(a \cap b)$$

of which it can be easily obtained by partitioning $a$ into subsets which contain $b$ and doesn't.

But clearly $-p(a \cap b) \neq  p(a \cup b)$.

Comment: I wrote it down wrong. I know of the identity n(a   n b’)=n(a)-n(a n b)

Comment: just use the property that $a \cap \bar{b}$ and $a \cap b$ are mutually exclusive and finite additivity.